# Better than Sliced Bread on Wheels!

Tags: visual, knowledge, steganography

So I got this idea to start up my own company, **Chowzen Corporation.**

I'm fairly confident that when it goes public, it's gonna make [Alibaba and Facebook](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/011215/top-10-largest-global-ipos-all-time.asp) look like a couple of turd smokers.

I've got a few "original" logo ideas here, but I'm stuck on a minor point for my business model. I'm still trying to decide **what my corporation should *do.***

> **Any Ideas on what this company should do?**

[image]

Comment: I want to say "Make Puzzles", but I have no real reasoning...

Comment: Is the last one [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Rkkba Zbovy$]$? Just clarifying.

Comment: 3 is rot13(havirefvglbsbxynubzn).

Comment: I like the visuals (obviously), but I think the puzzle would look better without the purple number-bullets on them. I don't think the confer any important information, or do they? (If sequence is important and couldn't be guessed, putting your logos in that sequence would still look better.)

Comment: @BmyGuest I've been trying to avoid making puzzles that take up a lot of vertical real estate, and I wanted numbers so that people could do that thing they do ("I think number 8 refers to Adidas").

Comment: @Chowzen Well, a raster with more subtle numbering would have done it as well, I guess. But as said, it's just a personal impression on "esthetics", not something bad about the puzzle. But is Astralbee's [solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/68514/5840) not correct yet?

Comment: Well, whatever are you gong to do in your company, you know what they say... Just Do It :D

Comment: Where does bread on wheels come in?

Comment: @Jǝssǝ It's just part of the "flavor," the non-essential back story of this puzzle. My incredible optimism in my fictitious new company is reflected in how well I think it will do in its IPO and by the fact that I think that people will say it's better than [sliced bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliced_bread#In_popular_culture), more important than the invention of the [wheel](https://interestingengineering.com/35-inventions-that-changed-the-world).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your company should:

> Design icons.

Because...

> The first letters of all the logos you imitated spell out:
>
>   **I**BM
>  **C**oca Cola
>  **O**klahoma Sooners
>  **N**ike
>
>  **D**ell
>  **E**xxon
>  **S**ubway
>  **I**ntel
>  **G**oogle
>  **N**Vidia
>
>  (**ICON DESIGN**)
>
>  And judging by the fact you've designed all these logos, you'd probably be very good at it, too!

Comment: That's it! An Iconic answer if I ever saw one. Your ✔️ is in the mail.

Answer (score 4):

1.

> [Google](http://logok.org/google-logo/)

2.

> [Intel](http://1000logos.net/intel-logo/)

3.

> [University of Oklahoma](https://www.ou.edu/web/) (@humfuzz)

4.

> [Subway](http://www.subway.com/en-GB)

5.

> [Dell](https://www.dell.com/en-uk?~ck=mn)

6.

> [Coca-Cola](https://www.coca-cola.co.uk/)

7.

> [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/)

8.

> [nVidia](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/page/home.html)

9.

> [Nike](https://www.famouslogos.net/nike-logo/)

10.

> [Exxon](https://www.logodesignlove.com/exxon-logo-raymond-loewy)

After all this however, the corporate identity **Chowzen** is yet to be decided!

You could try [dog food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_Chow), or more generally, pet products. I hear [cat scratchers](http://www.petsathome.com/shop/en/pets/cat/cat-scratching-furniture) are coming back!

Comment: Hmmm... I *do* like dog food... Maybe the logos and/or the nature of my question would point to something more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

All of the logos are related to real life logos:

1.

> Google

2.

> Intel (Pre 2005)

3.

> University of Oklahoma

4.

> Subway

5.

> Dell

6.

> Coca Cola

7.

> IBM

8.

> Nvidia

9.

> Nike

10.

> Exxon Mobil

Comment: Perhaps the last one could be [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Rkkba Zbovy$]$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after but each logo reminds me of something, the one thing that seems to tie these together is:

> Fast (sports and fast food) and Computers...so making fast computers?

1.

> This colour scheme reminds me of Google - a search engine

2.

> 

3.

> 

4.

> Subway - Sandwich shop

5.

> Dell - Make computers

6.

> 

7.

> IBM - Also make computers (among other things)

8.

> Nvidia - Make graphics cards

9.

> Nike - Sports wear

10.

> 